# AJAX reference error on form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX script which is for a contact form on my page

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var contactForm = $('#contactForm');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        :
        :
```

**HTML**

```
 <form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" action="php-scripts/contact-form.php" method="post">
           <label for="name">Name</label>
           <br />
           <input type="text" name="name" id="conName" />
           <br />
           <label for="email">Email</label>
           <br />
           <input type="text" name="email" id="conEmail" />
           <br />
           <label for="phone">Phone</label>
```

**My Problem**

On my web console I get the error:

> ReferenceError: form is not defined

```
$(form).submit(function(e)
```

As a newbie to AJAX I cant see why I am getting this error, any help will be appreciated

If you need any more info to help please let me know

Comment: form is not undefined either use $('form' ) or use contactForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no variables called `form` defined. Most probably missing the `quote`s around `form` -

```
$('form').submit(function(e)
```

OR `contactForm` is defined

```
contactForm.submit(function(e)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help will accept when time expires